# Inheriting forms duplicates controls into designer

Tags: c#, windows, forms, winforms, designer

I have a problem with inheriting in Windows Forms.
I created a base form class with some controls and events and a class which inherits from the base class. When I try to open the designer of the inherited class it gives me this error message: "Duplicate component name .... Component names must be unique and case-insensitive".

So this error message appears because it copied some (not all) of the controls of the base form into the designer.cs of the inherited form. All of my controls are 'protected'.

Why it copies some of the controls in general and why not all?

Comment: Is there any code in the load event of the base form ? Or in the ctor ?

Comment: A derived Form doesn't *copy* Controls, it just redefines their aspect if some properties have been changed in the derived Form's UI Designer. This is possible because you have set the Access Modifier to `Protected`. But this, per se, doesn't generate any kind of duplication, since there's isn't one.  -- You need to specify (clearly, since this is not the first time you have posted this question) how you built the base Form, how you derived other Forms and what code you have in the initialization procedures of the base Forms and the derived Forms.

Comment: Also post the .Net version in use (it affects the available Templates).